How does the metric transition from a falling dust-like sphere to the Schwarzschild metric?
Outside a static spherically symmetric body in vacuum lies the Schwarzschild metric. However, when observing a falling sphere from a point near the sphere, it no longer appears spherical. Its opposite end appears stretched for an observer stationary relative to the center of the sphere. In this case, should gravity on the surface of the sphere instantly transition to the Schwarzschild metric? Or is there a transitional metric above the surface of the falling sphere with a thickness approximately $$2 \cdot r \cdot \frac{{dr}}{{dt}} \cdot \frac{1}{c}~?$$
The radius of the shell is considered a lot more than the gravitational Schwarzschild radius.

Is the word 'collapsing' applicable only for black holes? Therefore, I replaced the word 'collapsing' for the word 'falling'.

There is a famous result in general relativity known as Birkhoff's Theorem. It states that any vacuum patch of a spacetime presenting spherical symmetry is a patch of the Schwarzschild spacetime. In other words, the only spherically symmetric solution to the Einstein field equations in vacuum is the Schwarzschild solution.
Now, what is spherical symmetry? Spherical symmetry does not depend on how things look for a given observer. They are much more fundamental and completely observer-independent. As discussed in Wald's General Relativity, spherical symmetry means that the isometry group of the spacetime has an $\mathrm{SO}(3)$ subgroup. Notice that this is much more fundamental than what a single observer can see.
In your example, you assumed spherical symmetry. Therefore, the only possible solution outside the dust sphere is the Schwarzschild solution. There is no transition metric above the surface: you just get the Schwarzschild solution.
Of course, the story is different at the surface (assuming you are indeed considering a dust ball and not a spherical shell). The metric at the surface must satisfy something known as the junction conditions, which are restrictions on how the geometry behaves at the interface between two different metrics that are "glued" together. These are similar to the conditions one has on surfaces in electromagnetism, which usually include surface charges and similar constructions. The junction conditions tell that

the metric induced at the surface is well-defined (so the solutions on the two sides need to be well-matched)
a tensor known as the exterior-curvature has a good behavior depending on the matter content on the surface itself (this is similar to how you can have discontinuities in the electromagnetic field due to a surface charge density)

In short, the solution outside the dust sphere is always Schwarzschild (as long as you assume spherical symmetry) and it can't depend on the observer. Nevertheless, you have interesting geometrical structures at the surface separating the dust region from the vacuum region.
You can learn more about junction conditions in the books by Poisson (A Relativist's Toolkit), Misner, Thorne, and Wheeler (Gravitation), and Padmanabhan (Gravitation: Foundations and Frontiers).

Thank you for the link to the Birkhoff's theorems. It is counterintuitive for the dynamic. It applies to vacuum and utilizes $d{s^2} =  - Bd{t^2} + Ad{r^2} + {r^2}\left( {d{\theta ^2} + {{\sin }^2}\theta d{\phi ^2}} \right)$ But vacuum is not always present for the compression of the sphere at the considered point around sphere. Initially, there is matter at the point, then vacuum is present at the point. $d{s^2} =  - B(r,t)d{t^2} + A(r,t)d{r^2} + C(r,t)drdt + {r^2}\left( {d{\theta ^2} + {{\sin }^2}\theta d{\phi ^2}} \right)$ needs to be considered outside the scope of the Birkhoff's theorem.

@Imyaf as soon as the dust leaves the point, the spacetime becomes Schwarzschild. Birkhoffs theorem doesn't look to the spatial points, it looks to the spacetime points. The fact that at a particular time that point had dust is unimportant. As soon as it is vacuum, Birkhoff kicks in.
